# What is the best way to handle multiple transactions having transaction size exceed 1232 bytes

Tags: transactions, send-transaction, sign

How can I handle multiple transactions which have [more than the limit of 1232 bytes](https://solana.com/docs/programs/deploying).
I can do this like

**Case 1:**

```
transactions= []
transactions.push(txn1)
transactions.push(txn1) 
signed = signAllTransactions(transactions)
for(let i=0; i < signed.length; i++){
sendRawtransaction(signed[i])
}
```

I want to know that how these transactions will handle ? Are these transactions will be handled by solana runtime ?

However I can do this like to add all transactions into one go like

**Case 2:**

```
transaction = new Transaction()
transaction.add(txn1)
transaction.add(txn2)
signed=signTransaction(transaction)
sendRawTransaction(signed)
```

But I can not do this like in my case because all my transactions having larger transaction size than 1232 bytes. So, I can use **Case 1** but need to know how I can handle these multiple transactions in **case 1** **??** because I just pushed the transactions into an array and send and confirm transaction one by one.

How can I handle if one fails and other should not be executed and if last fails all should not be confirmed ? Are these handled by solana runtime according to the **case 1**

Answer (score 2):

Currently in case 1 your transactions will both be sent and will attempt to be executed whether either fails, effectively running them in parallel. The usual way to handle dependent transactions is to confirm one before sending the next.